# How to mint in solidity with the contract address as the receiver?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, polygon, smartcontracts

I'm trying to implement a contract that mints NFTs to the contract and can be transfered after that.

This is my mint function:

```
    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(address(this), tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
}
```

I get this error in testing:
Should set the right owner:

```
  AssertionError: expected '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f641…' to equal '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb…'
  + expected - actual
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Can I hard code the address on the mint function?

Comment: we dont know what your testing...

Comment: That error is from a test, not from the contract. Post your test code too.